# Update millions of database row using Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I'm wondering on which is the best for this
**Here is my Entity:**

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class User {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private Status status;
    private String statusRemarks;
}
```

**Option 1 Direct bulk update in UserRepository:**
Does this will affect my database performance if the users to be update will reach to millions in number?

```java
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("UPDATE u FROM User u set u.status=:status, u.statusRemarks=:statusRemarks where u.status in :statuses")
    void bulkUpdateByStatuses(Status status,String statusRemarks,Status... statuses);
}
```

**Option 2 will fetch the users by status and will update it one by one like this:**
I'm pretty sure this will affect the performance of the MS due to the memory usage

```
public void bulkUpdateUserByStatuses(final UserBulkUpdateDto userbulkUpdateDto){
        List<User> toUpdateUsers = userRepository.findByStatuses(userbulkUpdateDto.getStatuses())
        for(final User user: toUpdateUsers){
            user.setStatus(userbulkUpdateDto.getNewStatus());
            user.setStatusRemarks(userbulkUpdateDto.getStatusRemarks());

        userRepository.save(user);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely option 1.

Both options read the affected data, modify it and write it back.

The option 2 on top of that reads and writes the data across the network and turns it into java objects.

So it will be slower and probably even put a higher load on the database.

If the load still becomes to high for the database you should consider breaking the update in smaller ones, for example by limiting to a range of ids at a time.